# Что эффективнее, 1 ContentProvider для нескольких баз данных или каждый под свою?

Tags: android, contentprovider, java

В принципе, я больше чем уверен, что все будут говорить (кто в теме), что 1 будет лучше,чем несколько, но хотелось бы узнать общее мнение, может у кого-то будут свои полезные **обоснованные** доводы на этот счёт...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Все зависит от конкретной задачи, логики задачи если угодно. Если логика задачи требует, чтобы у вас был 1 курсор возвращающий значения из нескольких БД/таблиц - так тому и быть.
2. Здесь все таки важен вопрос разные БД или разные таблицы. Я бы не советовал объединять 2 разные БД в один `ContentProvider` - трансграничный запрос штука достаточно дорогая в плане ресурсоемкости, а вот разные таблицы - пожалуйста. В терминах SQL это все `inner/left/right join` - на это все СУБД заточены.
3. Если логика требует объединения нескольких БД (не таблиц, а именно БД) в один `ContentProvider` - то это на мой взгляд уже архитектурный изъян - либо неверно спроектирована БД, либо задача какая-то "левая".
4. У `ContentProvider` - есть еще другая важная задача, а именно публикация внутренних ресурсов программы БД наружу. Например, напрямую достучаться штатными средствами до БД СМС/ММС невозможно, а вот через `ContentProvider` - пожалуйста. Отсюда и вывод. Если в будущем планируется какие-то БД/таблицы/ресурсы "высунуть" наружу - то тут без `ContentProvider` уже никак (нужен флаг в манифесте `exported=true`)